# Não consigo chamar uma string

Tags: c, string, struct

Criei um algoritmo que simula um estoque de uma venda de dvd's. Ele armazena nome, preço e quantidade. Tem algumas funções e entra elas, uma que informa a quantidade e o preço de um dvd específico e é nela que estou tendo problemas.

Após chamar a função e puxar os dados da struct, deveria exibir o nome, o preço e as unidades. Meu problema é que só consigo pesquisar e retornar strings com até 3 letras.

Exemplo: Se eu cadastrar e depois buscar por “Max”, dá certinho, mas se for “Maax”, ele não encontra nada.

Segue o código caso alguém saiba me ajudar

```
void pesquisa(struct locadora v4[MAX])
{   int x;
char pesquisa[100];
printf ("\nInforme o nome de qual Dvd você quer buscar: ");
scanf("%s", &pesquisa);
for(x=0;x<MAX;x++)
    if ( strcmp ( pesquisa, v4[x].dvd)==0)
        printf ("\nO preço do dvd %s é R$ %.2f. Ele possui %d unidades em estoque!!\n", v4[x].dvd, v4[x].preco, v4[x].quant);
    else
            printf ("\nNão foi encontrado nenhum registro com esse nome");
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O teu erro esta no `scanf()`.

```
scanf("%s", &pesquisa);
```

A forma correcta é

```
scanf("%s", pesquisa);
//          ^ sem &
```

Ainda podes limitar a possibilidade de *buffer overflow* se introduzires o numero maximo de caracteres a ler

```
scanf("%99s", pesquisa);
```

E ainda deves sempre verificar o valor devolvido

```
if (scanf("%99s", pesquisa) != 1) /* erro */;
```

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda, PMG, mas ainda não funcionou. Tens alguma outra sugestão?

Comment: No [ideone funciona](http://ideone.com/cjsW4q) ... mas precisas de mudar os prints para fora do loop, senao ele imprime o resultado da pesquisa para cada elemento da base de dados. Ou seja ... podes imprimir o encontrado mal o encontres (e sair da funcao), mas tens de percorrer o array todo ate decidir que nao existe, e so entao imprimir resultado negativo.

Comment: Olhei seu código no ideone e vi que tinha setado um valor errado na struct só pra facilitar os testes. Estava bugando por causa disso. Valeu